# Spring Boot, using oracle-ldap url through ssh tunnel on local machine

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, ldap

There are 3 machines: 
`local -> some remote server -> oracle db server (via ldap)`

**I want to set up datasource connection (in my spring boot app) to the oracle db.**
There is no direct connectivity between local machine and the one with oracle db.
So, i'm using the ssh tunnel through remote server:

ssh -L 127.0.0.1:8081:some.ldap.host:389 user@remote.server.host

In application.yml file i'm using further url:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://127.0.0.1:8081//srvcnm,cn=OracleContext,dc=yy,dc=xx,dc=com
```

And when my app trying to get db connection, im getting the following error:

```
Caused by: oracle.net.nt.TimeoutInterruptHandler$IOReadTimeoutException: Socket read timed out
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.handleInterrupt(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:254)
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.connect(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:103)
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.<init>(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:77)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:192)
    ... 126 common frames omitted
```

Whenever i'm deploying app on the remote server and enter "direct" url in application.yml the connection is being obtained without any timeouts, and the app works well.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://some.ldap.host:389//srvcnm,cn=OracleContext,dc=yy,dc=xx,dc=com
```

Does anyone know how to handle this? How to get connection from local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in redirecting source connection request to another machine with oracle db itself (after ldap auth).
So, the request's path looked like:

```
1.local -> 2.remote server -> 3.ldap server -> 4.oracle db server
```

There wasn't connectivity between **1st** and **4th** machine as the tunnel was only between **1th** and **3rd** one.

So, you if you faced this issue, you may add one more ssh tunnel (First tunnel is for ldap server, second one for oracle db) and enrich your "etc/hosts" with oracle server's routing.

In my case the issue was in access restrictions. The oracle server is filtering sockets somehow and grants access to certain machines.

Answer (score 0):

I may do some thing like this, I am going to create file call `~/.ssh/config` then add following

```
Host remoteserver1
        User usermane
        Hostname ip or host name
        ForwardAgent yes
Host oracleserver
    User username
    Hostname some.ldap.host
    Port 22
   # ForwardAgent yes if you need to forward one more instance
    LocalForward 8081 some.ldap.host:389
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p remoteserver1
```

What this does is that when I attempt to connect to ssh oracleserver from remoteserver1, it connects to hopper and then proxies the SSH connection to port 22 on overthere (ie: SSH on oracleserver).

now to connect via ssh do following `ssh oracleserver` , as it will make ssh tunnel between your machine and oracleserver via remoteserver1. along with port forwarding.

Comment: The problem is, there is any other way to connect to db host except ldap's 389 port.
So, ssh on oracleserver won't work

Comment: so I am assuming remoteserver1 is already connected with oracleserver with port 389

Comment: yep, it has direct access to 389 port